# The SP is not applied to the first row of the table

Tags: mysql

I tried to update a column in a table using stored procedures called customer_Type().
here is the code I wrote:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE orderCount INT;
  DECLARE customerID INT;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
SELECT customer_id into customerID from customer LIMIT i,1;
SELECT COUNT(ord_no) into orderCount
    FROM orders
    where orders.customer_id= customerID;

    CASE orderCount
        WHEN 1 THEN
        update customer SET customer_Type= 'One-time Customer' where customer_id = customerID;
        WHEN 2 THEN update customer SET customer_Type='Repeated Customer' where customer_id = customerID;
        WHEN 3 THEN update customer SET customer_Type='Frequent Customer'  where customer_id = customerID;
        ELSE  update customer SET customer_Type= 'Loyal Customer' where customer_id = customerID;

    END CASE;

  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

END
```

the output is true for all customer but the SP didn't work with the first customer, it didn't update his type.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTra3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind:

A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is quite meaningless. There is no order in a relational database. It could return any row it wants to.

Second thing:

Instead of a `WHILE` loop, one would usually use a [`CURSOR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html) in cases like this.

Third thing:

You don't need a procedure for this at all. One statement is enough to solve your problem:

```
UPDATE customer c
JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, COUNT(ord_no) AS orderCount
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customer_id
) o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
SET c.customer_Type = CASE WHEN o.orderCount = 1 THEN 'One-time Customer'
                           WHEN o.orderCount = 2 THEN 'Repeated Customer'
                           WHEN o.orderCount = 3 THEN 'Frequent Customer'
                           ELSE 'Loyal Customer' 
                      END;
```

Fourth thing:

When a customer hasn't ordered anything at all, yet, the customerType isn't updated. You should add this case, too, I guess. For this turn the JOIN into a LEFT JOIN and add another case.

```
UPDATE customer c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, COUNT(ord_no) AS orderCount
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customer_id
) o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
SET c.customer_Type = CASE WHEN o.orderCount = 1 THEN 'One-time Customer'
                           WHEN o.orderCount = 2 THEN 'Repeated Customer'
                           WHEN o.orderCount = 3 THEN 'Frequent Customer'
                           WHEN o.orderCount IS NULL THEN "hasn't ordered yet"
                           ELSE 'Loyal Customer' 
                      END;
```

Or maybe in a better way to read:

```
UPDATE customer c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, COUNT(ord_no) AS orderCount
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customer_id
) o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
SET c.customer_Type = CASE COALESCE(o.orderCount, 0) 
                           WHEN 0 THEN "hasn't ordered yet"
                           WHEN 1 THEN 'One-time Customer'
                           WHEN 2 THEN 'Repeated Customer'
                           WHEN 3 THEN 'Frequent Customer'
                           ELSE 'Loyal Customer' 
                      END;
```

Comment: thank you! it works by adding order by clause, it is just an example for my students to use procedures.